# Architecture change to handle huge records in single table of MySQL with 5K DB connections support

Tags: mysql, database, connection

70 java client make around 1500 simultaneous connection every 10 minutes on single table to insert records. Table contains 300M records. Number of records on table not growing fast now as keep only 1 week data in table. 
Suggestion required on best approach as need to double the number of client (i.e. 150) with around 5000 simultaneous connections. As client increase records in table would be double (i.e. 600M).

1. Can MYSQL support 5000 connections?
2. As client size increase, records in table will be around 600M. Do we need to keep separate table for new clients. So 300M records in each table? or It would be better to add new server to entertain new clients.
3. Any DB parameter to optimize insert sql?

Comment: Why making 70 client not 70 connection. what Storage engine you using. how many records the writes a one time. show the table schema. tell a little more about your problem

Comment: 1. 70 remote clients (will be increase to 150 near future). Per client around 25 connection. all 70 client fire insert cmd simultaneously to DB. 2. InnoDB 3. DB has only one table with 12 columns. Column size not more than varchar(100).

Comment: -You must reduce the transaction, so that every client only write every 2,4 or 8 insert at once ( 1 Insert statement). lets say you have a HD with 15K rpm, so you can only write 250 transaction per sec (15000/60 worst case). a transaction will include a write to the HD). or you install a second HD or SSD for this hight write load.

Comment: Currently 1500 transactions max. that should be finished in 6 seconds (if we take the case of 15K RPM disk). Thats fine for me. If i increase max connection to 6K it will support or not? Do you see any challenge inserting records if single table contains 600M records? Do i need to seperate tables on same DB server or new Hardware server with mysql will be required?

Comment: YES - anything is OK,.... but there are may option like **Interleaved Lock Mode**. so when 2 clients simultan insert a row there are 2 ways. first is: the second insert waits for finish the transaction (also single transaction) and insert then the second row. the second is that the second insert not wait for finish. in this case its possible that when the first insert not finished (rollback) you have a hole in the auto increment values. we have a productive system with 3000 connections and 2000 used ...

Comment: and worked fine. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/auto_increment-handling-in-xtradbinnodb/ . you also can sent me a email, then we can phone about it and put the result later here in.

Comment: @Armit - you can use **Partitioning** for InnoDB then the table and index is internal splittet to more files. so if a query only use one partition there is a small index and also a small datafile. Also use FILE_PER_TABLE in you config. then every table stores his data in a separated file. it must before create table or you must copy into a new.

Comment: Thanks Bernd. Table is for statistics only and generally rollback not happen. Can explore "Interleaved Lock Mode". Need to hold 3 month data  so planning for 3 partition. Also planning to keep only active data in main table and will move old data in history table. I believe MySQL will handle 5K-6K connections and 500-600 M records in partitioned (3) table. 300M records create around  24GB data file, so 600M records may need around 50GB data file. Will keep data file separate for each partition. So in that case we need dont need a new Hardware Server to handle extra traffic. Please comment